# After end of result set

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I have sql query, which I run in MysqlWorkBench and here is the result:

```
order_id, customer_id,          date,          product_id, quantity
  '1',        '1',      '2014-07-30 01:20:46',    '1',         '7'
  '1',        '1',      '2014-07-30 01:20:46',    '2',         '3'
  '1',        '1',      '2014-07-30 01:20:46',    '3',         '2'
  '1',        '1',      '2014-07-30 01:20:46',    '7',         '1'
```

now I'm trying to get the same result in my app, here is the code

```
 public synchronized List<Order> getAllOrders() throws DatabaseException{                                      
List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();
Connection connection = null;
PreparedStatement statement = null;
ProductDao productDao = new ProductDao();
try{
    try {            
        connection = ConnectionPool.getInstance().getConnection();            
        statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT order_id,customer_id,`date`,product_id,quantity FROM 4elements.purchase as r INNER JOIN product_in_order d ON r.id = d.order_id");                        
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();            

        while (result.next())
        {
            Order order = new Order(); 
            int i = 1;
            order.setId(result.getInt(i++));
            order.setCustomerId(result.getInt(i++));              
            order.setDate(result.getTimestamp(i++));                
            int productId = result.getInt(i++);
            Item item = new Item(productDao.getProduct(productId));
            item.setQuantity(result.getInt(i++));
            orders.add(order);               
        }            
    }
    finally{                                        
        closePreparedStatement(statement);
        returnConnection(connection);                    
    } 
    return orders; 
}
```

I use my own `ConnectionPool` (it's part of the task) if it's important.
When I try to get the first int, I get `"After end of result set"` exception.
I tried use `Statement` instead of `PreparedStatement` - the same exception.
I also tried to take the results by the column name and it that case I could take only the first int from the result - and still I get exception.

Could, please, somebody tell me what is wrong?

Here is stacktrace:

```
   30-Jul-2014 11:47:05.110 INFO [http-apr-8080-exec-377] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start The start() method was called on component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/WebApp4Epam]] after start() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.
   java.sql.SQLException: After end of result set
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1094)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:997)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:983)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:928)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:850)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2705)
at dao.OrderDao.getAllOrders(OrderDao.java:64)
at command.GetOrdersCommand.execute(GetOrdersCommand.java:28)
at command.AdminLoginCommand.execute(AdminLoginCommand.java:31)
at controller.ControllerServlet.processRequest(ControllerServlet.java:51)
at controller.ControllerServlet.doPost(ControllerServlet.java:42)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at filters.EncodingFilter.doFilter(EncodingFilter.java:35)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:277)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2381)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2370)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

--ADDED--

I tried the other following on different table
       SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER

```
            statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER");                                                                
            result = statement.executeQuery();                 
            if (result.next()){
                customer = new Customer();                   
                customer.setId(result.getInt("id")); //I get an exception in that line
                customer.setFirstName(result.getString("first_name"));
                customer.setSecondName(result.getString("second_name"));                
            }
```

And get result after that, but it still gives me an exception.
Any ideas?

Comment: please show us the initial query used to retrieve those 4 rows in your example!

Comment: if the data shows as `'1'` then does this not mean it is a String not an int

Comment: Where exactly is the exception thrown? Post the stack trace!

Comment: @Albus: Post the exception that is thrown and leave a comment below

Comment: @wxyz the initial query is the same. I just copied the query from MysqlWorkbench to my code.

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?! - also note your call `i++` will always return you the `customer_id` value - use the field index direct `i.e 1,2..5`.

Comment: Which line is line 64 in OrderDao?

Comment: @Bitmap It throws an exception on line where I'm trying to get the first result -  order.setId(result.getInt(i++));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice you didn't close the result set after use but you seems to return the db connection and used it in some other place.

From the [javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html):

> When a `Statement` object is closed, its
>   current `ResultSet` object, if one
>   exists, is also closed.

But since you seem to use a custom method to close statment I have no idea what you did in it. If somehow you failed to close the statment and still returns the connect to pool, you might run into problem.

I'd recommend going through all your code and close all result set after use and the problem might go away.

Comment: result.beforeFirst() doesn't help.

Comment: changed my answer after I saw the stack trace, see if this helps

Comment: No, I close statement in other method.

Comment: You're finally right, I didn't close ResultSet object in other part of my project. Thanks a lot!